# .htaccess re-write rule breaks on value change

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following rule in my .htaccess file and it works fine

```
RewriteRule ^eat/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?/?([0-9]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?/?$ /incl/pages/details.php?state=$1&city=$2&ID=$3&name=$4 [NC,L]
```

I need to modify the rule where the ID ($3) will be a 3 character alpha-numeric (always in caps) value and not a 3 digits as it is now.

I've tried but my rule stops working:

```
RewriteRule ^eat/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?/?([A-Z0-9]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)?/?$ /incl/pages/details.php?state=$1&city=$2&ID=$3&name=$4 [NC,L]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The issue most likely is all those `/?` which can lead to patterns matching longer or shorter parts of the subject than you would expect. Looks like you try to be lazy and use only a single rule to match a variable number of arguments. That is no robust.

Comment: @arkascha What do you mean? Shall I remove "?"

Answer (score 0):

To me this looks like you have an issue with a clear separation of the parameters. The way you use the question mark operator to implement a "lazy" rule able to rewrite a variable number of parameters will may issues if the capture groups match the same character sets.

Instead I suggest you specify separate rules for fixed numbers of parameters. That allows to not use that operator to such an extend:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^eat/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([A-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /incl/pages/details.php?state=$1&city=$2&ID=$3&name=$4 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^eat/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([A-Z0-9]+)/?$ /incl/pages/details.php?state=$1&city=$2&ID=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^eat/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /incl/pages/details.php?state=$1&city=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^eat/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ /incl/pages/details.php?state=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^eat/?$ /incl/pages/details.php [NC,L]
```

And a question: to you really need the `NC` flag? Is `eat` really written is different cases? Because it will meddle with your attempt to differ between groups capturing only upper case letters or upper and/or lower case letters.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).